# Add Event Lsitener for later added buttons

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, appendchild

I add Elements to my list. But the Event Listener is only working for buttons I added in Html, alltough they have the same class.

I tried to add the Event Listener, after i added the button, but that also wasn´t working.

Comment: Post your code please